# Getting vectors and eigenvalue from an eigenvector problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

I try to get the eigenvalue *m* and the vectors *a* & *h* from this eigenvector problem:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A⋅A^T⋅h=m⋅h$$
$$A^T⋅A⋅a=m⋅a$$

I started with this:

$$A^T = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A⋅A^T = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^T⋅A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and then i got the highest m with (Characteristic Polynomial):

$$-x^3 + 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$$

$$m≈\frac{3+√5}{2}$$

Now i don't really know what to do. I think i have to do this to get the core of the matrix?:

$$(A⋅AT−mE)⋅h⃗ =0$$

to get this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1-(\frac{3+√5}{2}) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-(\frac{3+√5}{2}) & 1 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1-(\frac{3+√5}{2})\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix} h_{1}  \\ h_{2} \\ h_{3} \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

But when i try to solve it i only get:

$$ h1 = 0 $$

$$ \frac{√5+1}{2} * h_{2} + h_{3} = 0 $$

$$ \frac{√5-1}{2} * h_{3} + h_{2} = 0 $$

=> so this??:

$$h⃗ = \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Am i solving it wrong or am i doing a mistake somewhere else? Anything could help!

**EDIT:**

After the fix i get this:

$$(A⋅AT−mE)⋅h⃗ =0$$

=>

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1-(\frac{3+√5}{2}) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-(\frac{3+√5}{2}) & 1 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 1-(\frac{3+√5}{2})\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix} h_{1}  \\ h_{2} \\ h_{3} \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

=>

$$ h_{1} = 0 $$

$$ \frac{1-√5}{2} * h_{2} + h_{3} = 0 $$

$$ -\frac{√5+1}{2} * h_{3} + h_{2} = 0 $$

=>

$$h_{3} * 0 = h_{3}$$

$$h_{2} = \frac{√5+1}{2} * h_{3}$$

=>

$$h⃗ = \begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1,62*x \\ x \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this the right solution for vector h?

Comment: The exact forms are horrific: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,+1,+0%7D,+%7B1,+0,+1%7D,+%7B1,+0,+0%7D%7D
Is the problem actually asking you for this?

Comment: I double checked the starting values. I'm confused too

Comment: Wait a minute, is it asking for the eigenpairs of $A$ or of $AA^T$? Your question is confusing.

Comment: It is asking for the eigenvalue m and the vectors h & a. With m i`m pretty sure its right. The vectors should be solved for the highest possible m.

Comment: You made a slight sign mistake. This is $\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}2 h_2+h_3=0$ and $h_2-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2 h_3=0$, you get $0 h_3=0$ so a free variable and $h_2=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2 h_3$. I verified with maple and the calculations are right otherwise.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! So my solution is h1=0, h2 free and h3 your equasion?

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/235653d2b45b

Comment: @zwim i updated my question. Is this now the right solution for h? Your bpaste.net link confused me more than it helped :D In your solution are no free h3s :/ If you post your answer as the answer to this question i can accept it and close the question. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: yes, it is ok. you can choose $x=1$ to get the result in the bpaste. In the bpaste, you have on the left the $3$ eigenvalues, and on the right, the $3$ eigenvectors in each column. So for $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}2$ which is $2^{nd}$ eigenvalue of $B=AA^T$ you read $(0,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2,1)$ in the $2^{nd}$ column on the right. You can verify other results in the same way.

Comment: I suspect a typo and want to move the unit from place 31 to place  32.